# Gnuplot incomplete numbers

Tags: label, gnuplot, font-size, figure

I tried to make the  palette numbers bigger using this: "set tics font ", 30", here my code:

```
set style lines 100 lt 5 lw 0.5  
set xlabel "x" font ",25" offset 0,-2
set ylabel "y" font ",25" offset -8,0
set tics font ", 30"
set xrange [0:25]
set yrange [0:4]
set samples 500
set isosamples 500

unset grid 
unset key  
set view map

f(x,y) = x**2 + y**2

splot f(x,y) with pm3d
```

But the numbers are not complete in the left side:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `rmargin` you can change the margin size on the right, and the `at screen 0.82` means at the 82% of the way to the right most part of the plotting window.

Adding that to your script,

```
set style lines 100 lt 5 lw 0.5  
set xlabel "x" font ",25" offset 0,-2
set ylabel "y" font ",25" offset -8,0
set tics font ", 30"
set xrange [0:25]
set yrange [0:4]
set samples 500
set isosamples 500

set rmargin at screen 0.82
set lmargin at screen 0.13

unset grid 
unset key  
set view map

f(x,y) = x**2 + y**2

splot f(x,y) with pm3d
```

I got this plot
[image]